# vue.js variable in Vuex store not accessible in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have  defined `BASE_URL` in Vuex `store/store.js`

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {    
        BASE_URL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8090',
        isAuthenticated: false
    }, 
    ...
```

and imported the store to `main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Routes from './routes'
import {store} from './store/store'


Vue.use(VueResource)

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: Routes,
    mode: 'history'
});


new Vue({
  store: store,
  el: '#app',
    router: router,

  render: h => h(App)
});
```

However, when I try to import `BASE_URL` in a component:

```
    computed: {
        BASE_URL () {
        return this.$store.state.BASE_URL;  
      }

  },
  methods: {

   login: function () {
            axios.post( BASE_URL + "/api/login", {
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password,
          }).then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
          });

      },
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: BASE_URL is not defined
    at VueComponent.login (webLogin.vue?e2e5:175)
    at Proxy.boundFn (...
```

What could be wrong here? How to fix it?

Comment: Most looks ok, try 'axios.post( this.BASE_URL + "/api/login", {'

Comment: You are right. I always forget this! Thanks, answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in code in method `login`:

```
login: function () {
        axios.post( this.BASE_URL + "/api/login", { // you must have this here
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password,
      }).then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
      });

  },
```